# How to navigate to specifically position on ListBox Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i have a listbox with a lot of items, and each items when clicked go to a new page, what i want is when i return from the second page, stay at the same position of the item is clicked!

Thats my list!

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" Loaded="ListView_Loaded" SelectedItem="true"  SelectionChanged="searchResultsList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="{x:Null}">
                                    <!--<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,15" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>-->
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <Border Width="80" Height="80">
                                                    <Image Source="{Binding Caminho}" />
                                                </Border>

                                                <StackPanel Margin="0,16,0,0" Grid.Column="2">
                                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding NomeCurso}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" />

                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WinRT you can write the following code in your page constructor to cache it, this way the positions will be intact after you go back to this page:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

And from your sample I cant really see if you are using `ListBox` or `ListView`, I will presume `ListView` which is better as the `ListBox` is somewhat not needed anymore.

One thing I also noticed is that you use a simple `{Binding}` for your `ItemsSource` so maybe it is reset every time you go back because of this (if you are doing something that does this, as this is not visible from your sample code). I always have an additional property of type `ObservableCollection` and bind to it for example `ItemsSource={Binding MyItems}`. This way the list is reset only when I reset the property `MyItems`.

Comment: So what i need to do is create a ObservableCollection and add all my stuffs , and use datacontext to binding Items to list ? this is a listbox! Thanks! @Kristian Vukusic